# Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'WritableDraft<Number>' and 'number'.ts(2365)

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

My code is

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type InitialState ={
    products: [],
    quantity: Number,
    total: Number,
}

const initialState:InitialState = {
  products: [],
  quantity: 0,
  total: 0,
}

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.total += action.payload.price;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

I get the following error on `state.quantity += 1;`

> (parameter) state: WritableDraft Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'WritableDraft' and 'number'.ts(2365)

And this error on `state.products.push(action.payload);`

> (parameter) action: {payload: any;type: string;
> } Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

What am I doing wrong?
I am fairly new to Typescript and redux.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe typo, the TS type of a number should be `number`, NOT JavaScript `Number` constructor. The type should be:

```
type InitialState = {
  products: any[];
  quantity: number;
  total: number;
};
```